# Download progress for a dynamic import

Tags: javascript, fetch, dynamic-import

I want to dynamically import a big module and display the download progress. Is it possible? How can I implement this?

Note: the code lives in a webworker

Attempt: the problem is that `import()` only returns a Promise and if using fetch to read the stream I don't know how to 'decode' the data as a module or whether it is possible.

```js
let response = await fetch('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/pyodide/v0.20.0/full/pyodide.js');

const reader = response.body.getReader();
// Get total length
const contentLength = +response.headers.get('Content-Length');

// Read data
let receivedLength = 0;
const chunks = [];
while (true) {
    const { done, value } = await reader.read();

    if (done) {
        break;
    }

    chunks.push(value);
    receivedLength += value.length;
}

// Concatenate chunks
let chunksAll = new Uint8Array(receivedLength);
    let position = 0;
    for (let chunk of chunks) {
        chunksAll.set(chunk, position);
        position += chunk.length;
    }

// Decode ??
let result = new TextDecoder('utf-8').decode(chunksAll);
```